# Systemverilog coverage bins

Tags: system-verilog, function-coverage

I'm using system verilog coverage and i want to check bins range.
I want it to be within the range 1000-2000
But only he values that are in mod 5 will be sampled.
For example 1000, 1005, 1010 etc.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this is easily possible in SV 2012. Here's how it would look in your case:

```
coverpoint x {
  bins mod5[] = {[1000:2000]} with (item % 5 == 0);
}
```

You can read more in section 19.5.1.1 of the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). If you don't have an older simulator that can just do SV 2009, then you have to define the values by hand.